# Can hook_field_extra_fields be used with field collections?

Tags: entities

I have a field collection view that I have to manipulate some data on before it gets displayed, so I was going to use hook_field_extra_fields with the extrafield_views_integration module.  This worked great for me on nodes, but I'm not seeing the extra field get displayed on field collections.  Is there any way to get around this?

```
function my_module_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra['field_collection']['my_field_collection']['display'] = array(
    'some_extra_field' => array(
      'label' => 'TESTING FIELD 123',
      'description' => 'This is a test of hook_field_extra_fields on FCs',
      'weight' => 100
    ),
  );

  return $extra;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The entity name for a Field Collection is actually `field_collection_item` and not `field_collection` (if you run `var_dump(entity_get_info())` you'll see this).

This means your implementation should actually look as follows:

```
/**
 *  Implementation of hook_fields_extra_fields().
 */
function my_module_field_extra_fields() {
  $extra = array();

  $extra['field_collection_item']['my_field_collection']['display'] = array(
    'some_extra_field' => array(
      'label' => t('TESTING FIELD 123'),
      'description' => t('This is a test of hook_field_extra_fields on FCs'),
      'weight' => 100,
    ),
  );

  return $extra;
}
```

Also, dont forget your [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)'s ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this next time.  Unfortunately I've moved past this project.